# Applying the square root of operator on polynomial functions

Tags: performance-tuning, polynomials, memory, approximation

I am trying to apply an "operation" on polynomial functions: apply the operator $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-y\frac{\partial f}{\partial z})^2+(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+x\frac{\partial f}{\partial z})^2 $ to functions and then take the square root of it. But after certain rounds of operations, because of the square root, the denominators  became really complicated and the computer basically chocked. Is there any good way that I could solve the problem or I just have to switch to different programming software like Matlab ?

A small example:

```
xleft := Function[{f}, D[f, x] - y*D[f, z]/2];

yleft := Function[{f}, D[f, y] + x*D[f, z]/2];

lapl := Function[{f}, xleft[xleft[f]] + yleft[yleft[f]]]

laplsquaroot := Function[{f}, Sqrt[lapl[f]]]
```

When I used the Nest function here, `Nest[laplsquaroot, x^9 + y^6 + z^12, n]`, when n became larger than 5 the computer got chocked...

Any suggestion ??

Comment: The `LeafCount` of your test function increases with every step by a factor of about 140. For n=4 it is already 8,308,058. What else then a huge slowdown in the next steps were you expecting?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions ? I was thinking I could Fourier transform or ...

Comment: How exactly would MATlab help in this case?

Comment: One more result: For n=5, `LeafCount` is 1,603,393,231

Comment: Using `Simplify` at every step reduces `LeafCount` considerably (so it is possible to reach higher values of n than without it). But it is slow as well.